# How best to represent a relationship between rows in a single table?

Tags: sql, database-design, architecture

Imagine a data structure like this:

```
CREATE TABLE SuppressionList (
  SuppressionListId int(11) NOT NULL,
  ListName varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SuppressionListId`)
) 

INSERT INTO SuppressionList VALUES (1, 'MyFirstList');
INSERT INTO SuppressionList VALUES (2, 'MySecondList');
INSERT INTO SuppressionList VALUES (3, 'MyFirstListVariant');
```

In this scenario, MyFirstList and MyFirstListVariant are actually different flavours of the same thing. Up until this point, we had been told quite specifically that the requirements were to treat them as different entities and that the relationship between them was unimportant. Close to release, inevitably, there's now a requirement that the relationship needs to be acknowledged.

This is not a big table, and "variant" is a consistent piece of text, so it's *possible* to code this via flow control alone. But obviously I can see that being a future nightmare, just waiting to get bigger. I'd rather just knock this nail on the head once and for all.

My instinct for the simplest solution is to all a self-referential column, so:

```
CREATE TABLE SuppressionList (
  SuppressionListId int(11) NOT NULL,
  ListName varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  RelatedListId int(11) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`SuppressionListId`)
) 

INSERT INTO SuppressionList VALUES (1, 'MyFirstList', null);
INSERT INTO SuppressionList VALUES (2, 'MySecondList', null);
INSERT INTO SuppressionList VALUES (3, 'MyFirstListVariant', 1);
```

But that ... feels wrong somehow. I can see it being awkward when it's worked with as an ORM object for starters. Is this a sensible way to approach the problem? If not, what's a better one?

EDIT: for clarity, there will only ever be one "variant" per list - so this will never become a proper tree and will, at worst, be no more than one deep.

Comment: Is that a candidate for Slowly Changing Dimension Type 2 in DWH? Else this could be handled with proper Audit tables rather than a self reference

Answer (score 1):

This approach is one that is quite widely used.  It does however lead to the question as to how your are going to navigate through the data.

What will make a difference here is if you only have a 1 to 1 data structure, a many to one structure, and how many layers of data need to be traversed (i.e. would MyFirstListVariant2 map to ID 1 or ID 3)

This would define if you have a direct parent child relationship, or a grandparent, parent, child (Tree) structure.

If you have a tree structure then navigation can become complex - usually done in SQL via cursors or iterative cte. Neither of which have the best performance.  If you can give us a bit more detail on what your trying to achieve then we can make better suggestions based on how much data you have and how you intend to use it.

NB. Posted as answer because I wouldn't have put all this into a comment.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Edited the question to make clear this will only ever be a 1:1 relationship - no danger of a tree forming

Comment: In that case then your approach is sound.  This sort of connection is used regularly.  If you do not want to hold the data here then it is also possible to have a second table to hold the mapping.  It will depend now on where the information is going to be accessed from next and where it goes. If you have no tree structure and not many records then linking directly from the table back on itself shouldn't be a major problem, although you may want to consider adding a reference from 1 to 3 as well as 3 to 1 provided this is always 1:1. Good Luck.